# Rails link_to do block with remote=>true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to convert my `link_to` tag to a `link_to do` block, as discussed [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to). I'm not sure where the :remote=>true option should go.

Original:

```
<%= link_to "Title", {:controller => "users", :action => "edit", :id => u.id }, :remote => true %>
```

So far this is working for the `link_to do` block, but I don't know where to put :remote=>true. It doesn't work either in the options block or html_options.

```
<%= link_to (options = {:controller => "users", :action => "edit", :id => u.id}) do %>
     Link contents
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Didn't tested, but I think the right way is

```
<%= link_to (url_for({:controller => "users", :action => "edit", :id => u.id}), :remote => true) do %>
     Link contents
<% end %>
```

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction! Turns out you close the url_for before :remote=>true. Thank you, I'll update the question with what worked for me :)

Comment: @user1436111 Instead, create an answer. Answers don't belong in questions. Also, the `url_for` *is* closed before the `:remote`.

Answer (score 4):

Got it! Correct syntax is

```
<%= link_to (url_for({:controller => "users", :action => "edit", :id => u.id})), :remote => true do %>
     Link contents
<% end %>
```

Thanks.